# Create a new file with common and unique genes from two data frames in R

Tags: r

i have a dataframe with genes like this :

```
genes   padj
ENSG00000106714 3.43056474068292E-05
ENSG00000165115 9.165798954677E-05
ENSG00000188056 0.000846081653952
ENSG00000254340 0.003678623922293
ENSG00000196083 0.007632605419062
ENSG00000236438 0.007632605419062
ENSG00000223401 0.009219856694741
ENSG00000233013 0.010086733081366
ENSG00000214077 0.009703019961401
```

and another one like this

```
genes   padj
ENSG00000165115 2.0309880524746E-07
ENSG00000106714 8.28506484840271E-07
ENSG00000111087 3.65536414358691E-06
ENSG00000257743 2.38040674140299E-05
ENSG00000261804 6.68330615861441E-05
ENSG00000251260 0.000868563126637
ENSG00000223401 0.000868563126637
ENSG00000089505 0.001233018119198
ENSG00000213934 0.001735780758384
```

and i would like to create a new data frame in which i will have the common genes between the two files , the unique from file 1 and the unique from file 2.

Comment: Do you want unique `padj` values for the same genes in 2 files?

Comment: Try `df_all <- merge(df1, df2, by="genes", all=T)`

Comment: No padj is not playing an important role. I just want common genes between two files and unique from each file compared to the other file. So in total 3 columns lets say in another file with common, unique in file1 and unique in file2

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dplyr` library to create a new data frame containing common genes with unique `padj` with it.

Here's how you'll do it

```
library(dplyr)
df <- inner_join(genes1, genes2, by = 'genes')
df
```

The output will look like this:

```
           genes      padj.x      padj.y
1 ENSG00000106714 0.000034300 0.000000829
2 ENSG00000165115 0.000091700 0.000000203
3 ENSG00000223401 0.009219857 0.000868563
```

And if you want all the `genes` to show up in your data frame along with respective `padj` you can use `full_join` instead of `inner_join`.

```
df <- full_join(genes1, genes2, by = 'genes')
df
```

The output of `full_join` looks like this:

```
             genes      padj.x      padj.y
1  ENSG00000106714 0.000034300 0.000000829
2  ENSG00000165115 0.000091700 0.000000203
3  ENSG00000188056 0.000846082          NA
4  ENSG00000254340 0.003678624          NA
5  ENSG00000196083 0.007632605          NA
6  ENSG00000236438 0.007632605          NA
7  ENSG00000223401 0.009219857 0.000868563
8  ENSG00000233013 0.010086733          NA
9  ENSG00000214077 0.009703020          NA
10 ENSG00000111087          NA 0.000003660
11 ENSG00000257743          NA 0.000023800
12 ENSG00000261804          NA 0.000066800
13 ENSG00000251260          NA 0.000868563
14 ENSG00000089505          NA 0.001233018
15 ENSG00000213934          NA 0.001735781
```

Comment: So inner_join is to find the common genes between the two files. How i will find also those genes that are unique in file1 and those that are unique in file2 ? pdj is not so much important but ok for common it helps to have a table with this info.

Comment: To get the unique genes from let's say genes1 data frame, you need to do this: `unique(genes1$genes)`. It will give you a vector containing unique values of genese.

Answer (score 0):

Using `merge()` and subsetting after.

```
(df_all <- merge(df_x, df_y, by="genes", all=TRUE))  ## complete gene set
#              genes       padj.x       padj.y
# 1  ENSG00000089505           NA 1.233018e-03
# 2  ENSG00000106714 3.430565e-05 8.285065e-07
# 3  ENSG00000111087           NA 3.655364e-06
# 4  ENSG00000165115 9.165799e-05 2.030988e-07
# 5  ENSG00000188056 8.460817e-04           NA
# 6  ENSG00000196083 7.632605e-03           NA
# 7  ENSG00000213934           NA 1.735781e-03
# 8  ENSG00000214077 9.703020e-03           NA
# 9  ENSG00000223401 9.219857e-03 8.685631e-04
# 10 ENSG00000233013 1.008673e-02           NA
# 11 ENSG00000236438 7.632605e-03           NA
# 12 ENSG00000251260           NA 8.685631e-04
# 13 ENSG00000254340 3.678624e-03           NA
# 14 ENSG00000257743           NA 2.380407e-05
# 15 ENSG00000261804           NA 6.683306e-05
```

```
df_all[is.na(df_all$padj.y), ]  ## complete x set
#              genes       padj.x padj.y
# 5  ENSG00000188056 0.0008460817     NA
# 6  ENSG00000196083 0.0076326054     NA
# 8  ENSG00000214077 0.0097030200     NA
# 10 ENSG00000233013 0.0100867331     NA
# 11 ENSG00000236438 0.0076326054     NA
# 13 ENSG00000254340 0.0036786239     NA
```

```
df_all[is.na(df_all$padj.x), ]  ## complete y set
#              genes padj.x       padj.y
# 1  ENSG00000089505     NA 1.233018e-03
# 3  ENSG00000111087     NA 3.655364e-06
# 7  ENSG00000213934     NA 1.735781e-03
# 12 ENSG00000251260     NA 8.685631e-04
# 14 ENSG00000257743     NA 2.380407e-05
# 15 ENSG00000261804     NA 6.683306e-05
```

```
df_all[complete.cases(df_all), ]  ## common set
#             genes       padj.x       padj.y
# 2 ENSG00000106714 3.430565e-05 8.285065e-07
# 4 ENSG00000165115 9.165799e-05 2.030988e-07
# 9 ENSG00000223401 9.219857e-03 8.685631e-04
```

---

*Data:*

```
df_x <- structure(list(genes = c("ENSG00000106714", "ENSG00000165115", 
"ENSG00000188056", "ENSG00000254340", "ENSG00000196083", "ENSG00000236438", 
"ENSG00000223401", "ENSG00000233013", "ENSG00000214077"), padj = c(3.43056474068292e-05, 
9.165798954677e-05, 0.000846081653952, 0.003678623922293, 0.007632605419062, 
0.007632605419062, 0.009219856694741, 0.010086733081366, 0.009703019961401
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))

df_y <- structure(list(genes = c("ENSG00000165115", "ENSG00000106714", 
"ENSG00000111087", "ENSG00000257743", "ENSG00000261804", "ENSG00000251260", 
"ENSG00000223401", "ENSG00000089505", "ENSG00000213934"), padj = c(2.0309880524746e-07, 
8.28506484840271e-07, 3.65536414358691e-06, 2.38040674140299e-05, 
6.68330615861441e-05, 0.000868563126637, 0.000868563126637, 0.001233018119198, 
0.001735780758384)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```